# Which book has the right conditional independence formula?

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I'm getting crazy.

I've just started to learn probability and, after it, Bayesian networks. I don't know so much about probability, that is why I'm getting crazy.

I'm using this [book](http://www.ia.uned.es/~fjdiez/libros/intro-mgp.pdf) to study a subject of my master's degree. On pages 32 and 33 (PDF's pages 44 and 45), formula (1.50), it talks about conditional independence. And it says that:

1. $I_G(A,B|C) => P(a,b|c) = P(a|c)·P(b|c)$

And in the next page, in the formula (1.51) it says that:

$I_G(A,B|C) => I_P(A,B|C)$

But in Learning Bayesian Networks by Neapolitan book, page 19 (PDF's page 30), it says that:

2. $P(a|b,c)$ can be written as $I_p(A,B|C)$ when $P(a|b,c) = P(a|c)$

**Clarification:**
$I_p$ is the conditional independence given the probability distribution $p$ (joint probability function).

Which book is wrong? (or maybe both are correct because $P(a,b|c)$ and $P(a|b,c)$ are the same "thing" or I haven't understood anything).

Comment: For clarification - what is $I_p$?

Comment: @jbowman I have updated my question.

Comment: With reference to your first equation, I don't see that equation on page 44 at all.  I also don't see how the statement of independence can be *equated* to the conditional probability itself.

Comment: @jbowman I have updated my question again, and I've just started to learn it, so I don't know so much about it.

Comment: @jbowman $I_P$ notation is defined in Learning Bayesian Networks by Neapolitan book, page 18 (PDF's page 29).

Comment: That would be pages 32 and 33, not pages 44 and 45.  You might want to correct the quote from the Neapolitan book, since pretty clearly the statement $P(a,b|c) = P(a|c)P(b|c)$ returns a true/false value but $P(a|b,c)$ returns a probability, so you can't write $P(a|b,c)$ as $I_p(A,B|C)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring notation issues, both definitions of C.I. are equivalent, although the first definition in your question is the standard way of defining it.

To see that they are equivalent observe that if $\mathbb{P}(a,b|c) = \mathbb{P}(a|c)\mathbb{P}(b|c)$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(a|bc) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(abc)}{\mathbb{P(bc)}}\\
& = \frac{\mathbb{P}(ab|c)\mathbb{P}(c)}{\mathbb{P(bc)}}\\ 
& = \frac{\mathbb{P}(a|c)\mathbb{P}(b|c)\mathbb{P}(c)}{\mathbb{P(bc)}} & (\text{by hypothesis})\\
& = \frac{\mathbb{P}(a|c)\mathbb{P}(bc)}{\mathbb{P(bc)}}\\
& = \mathbb{P}(a|c)
\end{align*}$$

Likewise, you can multiply both sides of $\mathbb{P}(a|bc) = \mathbb{P}(a|c)$ by $\mathbb{P}(b|c)$ to show that the second definition implies the first.

Note that this is completely analogous to the non-conditional case where:
$$\mathbb{P}(ab)=\mathbb{P}(a)\mathbb{P}(b)\Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(a|b)=\mathbb{P}(a)$$

What the second definition of independence or, in your case, conditional independence, is saying is that, given $c$, the probability of $a$ also given $b$ is the same as the probability of $a$ if you didn't know $b$ (only $c$), i.e.,
**Given $c$, knowing $b$ tells you nothing about the probability of $a$**